# Missing call stack frames when debugging a crash dump with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

I'm trying to debug an access violation error in some native code, and I have the mini-dump for the crash.

When opening the crash dump with visual studio, here's what happens:

If VS can't find the symbols for my problematic native DLL, it shows the correct call stack frames (including the location in my code the error is generated from). But I can't see the sources, of course.

If VS can find the symbols (I put them in the correct location and the output window says that the symbols for MyProblematic.dll were loaded), I only see one frame in the call stack - which is msvcr90.dll. Obviously that doesn't help me much.

Can anyone explain this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it is easy to explain.  If the stack frame is corrupted then neither the minidump taker nor the debugger can walk the stack to show you more.  Easy to do, for example just strcpy() and overflow the end of the stack buffer so that the saved EBP and return address gets stomped.  And, yes, almost impossible to diagnose, no matter how good the quality of the minidump.  Good luck with it.